# extention functions $("#someId").button('loading') not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have been unable to use any function belonging to the Bootstarp js file, i have it referenced in the head of the aspx page. jquery is referenced before is up to date (1.9) and works fine.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

but i keep getting ".button is not a function" error when I try to do something with the extension functions for these components.  what could be the cause? or what parts of my code do you think are relevant? i have been able to run these functions on other pages, but the only difference i can find is thus page has a form element set to runat="server". could this have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

### no idea why but removing the form element from the page solves the problem. is the form making the  js file not load?

a div had the class set to ""form-horizantel" it conflicts with the form element somehow.